# partial view c# mvc

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

which folder should my partial view be so that it can recognize `@model`?

I have a main index page, once a person searches for a keyword, I have a viewmodel that filters the DB results and pass it to the partial view below:

Below is my partialview.cshtml for my search results under the "Shared" folder.

```
@model Namespace.ViewModels.ItemViewModel //<-------------this is not been recognized, @model does not exist in the current context 
@if (Model.SearchResults.Count == 0)
{
    <h3 class="text-error">No items matched your search query!</h3>
}
else
{
    foreach (var result in Model.NewsList)
    {
        // display search results
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are most likely working on an MVC4 or earlier project using Visual Studio 2015. Unfortunately, VS2015 does not provide correct parsing for pre-MVC5 projects and falsely reports this as an error.

The page will still work at runtime.

The only solutions that I am aware of are to use an earlier version of Visual Studio or [upgrade the project to MVC5](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2).

Comment: I am actually using the latest version of VS. Do I still need to use that format? it did compile however, it gave an error saying the namespace was not found. thanks.

Comment: Your version of VS and your version of MVC are two, independent things. Unless you have upgraded your project to MVC5 (I provided a link for that), you need to continue using the MVC4 syntax including the @model keyword that VS2015 objects to.

Comment: Yes my project is using latest MVC 5 not MVC 4. I was forced to do so when I was using system security instead of microsoft security. thanks. so do i use the same format or there is a better way for MVC 5. thanks again